# What is the difference between sh and shell for org-babel?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, org-table

I'm experimenting with sourcing data from org-mode into my shell scripts and I've run across a weirdness:

```
#+tblname: simple-table
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

#+name: work-with-simple-list-shell
#+begin_src shell :var tbl=simple-table
echo "$tbl"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: work-with-simple-list-shell
: 1

#+name: work-with-simple-list-sh
#+begin_src sh :var tbl=simple-table
echo "$tbl"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: work-with-simple-list-sh
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
```

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: It seems like ob-sh is deprecated in favour of ob-shell ( As seen in [this thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2014-02/msg00023.html) of the mailing list).

Comment: If they are only aliases to each other then why the difference in behaviour?

Comment: Something weird with your config. I don't see any difference in behaviour here. If I echo $SHELL, I get the same shell for both. Also, did you try `C-c C-v I` to check whether both src-blocks have the same header-args?

Comment: @dangom: hmm same set of header args save for Lang:shell vs Lang:sh and header-args:shell vs header-args:sh but both set to nil. $SHELL reports bash in both cases.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The difference is *which* shell gets called to evaluate your block.  `shell` calls whatever your default shell is while `sh` calls `/bin/sh` specifically. Your default shell is probably bash, which is an extension of sh.  `echo $0` will tell you what executable your shell is running:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell
echo $0
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: /bin/bash


#+BEGIN_SRC sh
echo $0
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: sh
```

Any of the shells in `org-babel-shell-names` that is installed on your system will work.

Comment: I'm still confused as to why the input variable gets so munged. Is this bash doing something different with the variable?

Comment: Yes: the table is passed as a list - in the `sh` case, the list is basically `mapconcat`-ed into a string; in the `bash` case, the list is assigned to an (indexed) array (try `echo ${tbl[@]}` as the body of the code block).